# Pass parameter value from url back to view module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to pass a parameter value from my url back to the view model. Here is the url: `StudentDetails/MarkingToolView/1?studentId=1`

I am trying to get the first parameter of 1 (after MarkingToolview/) so I can post it back to my database

my viewModel:

```
public class MarkingVM
{
    public int? ModuleID { get; set; }
}
```

my view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModuleID, new { id = ???  })
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you have an action that accepts MarkingVM as the argument?

Comment: Setting the `id` attribute does nothing with regards to posting your data (a form only submits a controls `name` and `value`). Not really clear what your trying to do.

Comment: [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult MarkingToolView( int? id, int? studentID)
        {
            
           return View(MyMarkingVM);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking how to get the url parameter into your view perhaps? Something like the following will populate your view model.

**Controller**

```
public action MarkingToolView(int studentId)
{

    MarkingVM vm = new MarkingVM(); //or however that is initialized.
    vm.ModuleID = studentId;
    return View(vm);
}
```